# How to verify the authenticated user in a google cloud function?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-identity

I'm attempting to use Google's Identity Platform in my Google Cloud function. I'm not finding any information about it. I imagine that I should be able to do something like this:

```
exports.helloWorld = (req, res) => {

   var user = getAuthenticatedUser(); //I made up this function and I'm imagining there's some API from google to do this.

   if ( user === undefined ) {
     res.status(403).send('Forbidden!');
   }

   let message = req.query.message || req.body.message || 'Hello ' + user;
  res.status(200).send(message);
};
```

Can somebody please direct me to the right documentation? I feel like I'm going in circles and failing to identify how this can be or should be done.

Thank you

Comment: Do you use private Cloud Function ? And you wan't to authorise only authenticated user to access to it, users which aren't registered in your project, any external user. Am I right?

Comment: My goal is to have users sign-in using Google's Identity Platform (this allows for email/password sign up or using social login like facebook, google, linkedIn and so on). Only users that have authenticated through that platform (which has configuration within my project) should be able to call my function. I hope this clarifies it. Thank you

Comment: Short answer: you can't. But I'm writing an article on Cloud Endpoint and how to secure access with API Key. But there is also a condition for Firebase Auth. You can try by yourselves. I flag this question, i will update the response when my article will be released, and I will make a special case for you with firebase auth (it's exactly the same thing as CIP)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your clarified use case, I believe what you are looking for is this:

[image]

You can follow the [Authenticating Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#end-users) guide (which is still in Beta) to make sure your Functions are only ran by authenticated users.

In short, the two options are Google Sign-In with a OAuth 2.0 Client ID that would do the authentication "itself" before the Function runs (saving you costs). The other is with Firebase, which does the authentication in the Function, which means you would get charged for unauthenticated requests.

Please let me know if this helped :)

Answer (score 0):

As promise, [here](https://medium.com/google-cloud/secure-cloud-run-cloud-functions-and-app-engine-with-api-key-73c57bededd1) my articles.

You have the basis for starting a proxy and to perform authentication, because directly it's not possible. In the article, the authentication is with API Key but you can plug [firebase identity provider](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/authenticating-users-firebase) -> It's the same platform as Cloud Identity Platform.

Hope this help!